Need to preview CR3 files in files application
In gedit I edited:
/usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer
I added:
image/x-canon-cr2;image/x-canon-cr3;image/x-canon-crw;
I cleared out my thumbnail cache and in "Files" application (version 46.2) I refreshed the display.
Canon CR3 files aren't displaying.
So my question is how can I preview CR3 images in files and folders? (Canons RAW format).
Running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
Thanks!

You may need to install Darktable.
